# how to pass parameters in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this page (called "page"). I tried calling those pages by id with `<%= link_to page.title, page_path(page.id) %>`which is working, but I want to call those pages using params, I don't want their link to be direct like http://localhost:3000/pages/6 but I want that id 6 to be passed through a params, so I'll have a link like http://localhost:3000/pages?category_id=1.

Here's my pages controller

```
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @pages = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def all
    @category = Category.find_by(id: params[:category_id])
    @pages = @category.pages
  end

  def index
    if params[:id].present?
      show
    else
     #Code of index action
     @pages = Page.all
    end
  end
end
```

and my show.html.erb

```
<%= @page.title %>
<%= @page.body %>
```

and then the link to this page

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <h4>
    <b>
      <%= link_to page.title, page_path(page.id)%>
    </b>
  </h4>
<% end %>
```

Comment: use the `index` action and then call `show` if your param is present

Answer (score 0):

There may be many ways to do this and my way is as follow.

---

Change `index` action of `pages_controller` as follow

```
def index
  if params[:id].present?
    show
  else
   #Code of index action
   @pages = Page.all
  end
end
```

Change `show` action of `pages_controller` as follow

```
def show
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
end
```

And pass page `id` in `link_to` function as follow

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <h4><b><%= link_to page.title, pages_path(:id => page.id)%> </b></h4>
  #<h4><b><a href="/pages?id=page_number">Page Title</a></b></h4>
<% end %>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: i want the page to open when i click on the title, not category list, i only want the page to be passed through a params

Comment: when i click on the page title, it takes me to the same page, how can i make it take me to a different page

Comment: i posted my full controller if it will help you help me